# Message Id's are known to change on move/copy/etc... But are they ever repeated?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Lets say I run the request `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`

I get back a list of `Message` objects. According to the documentation [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message)

> id (string) - Unique identifier for the message (note that this value may change if a message is moved or altered)

However, is this `id` ever repeated? Currently I am making a scheduling plugin that saves some message draft `id` to a database before attempting to send it at some specified later date

I know that if the message is moved or altered that the `id` will no longer be valid. But would it ever accidently point to a new (but different) message?

In other words, **are the `ids` every reused?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Ids are never repeated as far as I can say.

Answer (score 4):

The ID property is a compound value which, among other things, includes the message's path and it's unique identifier. This is why the ID will change when a message is moved to another folder but still maintain a unique value.

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed with the store team, mids (the message Id portion of an entry id) are never reused.